# Which annotations are scanned for with context:annotation-config?

Tags: spring

What is the list of annotations that are processed when I define `<context:annotation-config/>` in my beans config xml?

Comment: which version of Spring? that configuration option has been added to Spring 2.5 but last version (3.1) supports a larger set of annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context-ac):

> Activates the Spring infrastructure for various annotations to be detected in bean classes: Spring's @Required and @Autowired, as well as JSR 250's @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy and @Resource (if available), and JPA's @PersistenceContext and @PersistenceUnit (if available). Alternatively, you can choose to activate the individual BeanPostProcessors for those annotations explictly.

Comment: and the Spring's `@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Service`, etc. Last version even supports some of the CDI ones, i.e.: `@Inject`